# How to Install Azure Azcopy on Ubuntu/Debian from a repo

Tags: ubuntu, azure, azcopy

**I want to install Azure azcopy on a Ubuntu 20.04 and be certain that it comes from a legit source (not infected, corrupted etc).**

Recommended way is to [download it from MS site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) - at least [according to MS docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10). However - how can I verify it's authenticity ? Is there a way to verify checksum for the file I download from this link ?

Ideal way for me would be to be able to install it using `apt install' but I could't figure it out yesterday; I was trying to use this [tutorial](https://blog.e-zest.com/azure-azcopy-a-very-helpful-tool) - I just changed the repo to 'focal' but azcopy package isn't a part of it :(

Is there an official repo for 20.04 that contains azcopy ?

I'm open for any suggestions - **my goal is - to have a legit `azcopy` binary on the system**.

Comment: Why do you think a download from a repo is more legit than an https (therefore with publisher verification) download? It lacks some hash verification, but if it's not the original publisher who provides the package with checksums it won't have any benefit in terms of "being legit"

Comment: Our company unwritten rule is that we don't use any binaries downloaded from internet in production. As a compromise for the moment I'm just using `tar -tf filename` to check if it really consists azcopy inside. I'd love to have something better though.